# Android: load PropertyResourceBundle with variable name

Tags: java, android, properties

I´m trying to load ".properties" files into a PropertyResourceBundle object

It´s working with this code, but I have to load a lot of different  combinations.

```
static ResourceBundle res[] = {null, null, null};
res[i] = new PropertyResourceBundle(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.respaul_de));
```

These files are in res/raw/ directory of my android project.
Does someone knows a solution to do it like that...

```
res[i] = new PropertyResourceBundle(getResources().openRawResource("R.raw." + <nameArray> + <languageArray>));
```

I´ve tried it like that...but it didn´t work. Because I get always an ID of "0".

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("respaul_de", "id", getPackageName());
res[i] = new PropertyResourceBundle(getResources().openRawResource(resID));
```

I would be pleased if someone can help me.

**EDIT:**

**Solution:**

```
String n = resourceNames[i / 3].toLowerCase() + "_" + (lang[i % 3].toString()).toLowerCase();
        int is = getResources().getIdentifier(n, "raw", getPackageName());
        res[i] = new PropertyResourceBundle(getResources().openRawResource(is));
```

resolved:

```
int is = getResources().getIdentifier("respaul_en", "raw", getPackageName());
```